# Using `gets` when I'm running code using the ruby executable's STDIN

Tags: ruby, bash, stdin

How can I get I use "gets" when I'm running code using the ruby executable's STDIN?

Here's a test that you can execute on any bash prompt:

```
echo "print 'Enter: '; input = \$stdin.gets; puts 'Entered: ' + input" | ruby
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do as below:

`ruby -e "print 'Enter: '; input = \$stdin.gets; puts 'Entered: ' + input"`

You need the `-e` flag passed to ruby. From ruby man page:

> -e command     Specifies script from command-line while telling Ruby not to search the rest of the arguments
>                       for a script file name.